# Quotient topology and continuity

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a quotient map and Z be a topological space. Show that $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ is continuous iff $g\circ \pi:X\rightarrow Z$ is continuous.

**My attempt:**

$\Rightarrow:$ We know that $(X,\mathcal{T}_X),(Y,\mathcal{T}_Y),(Z,\mathcal{T}_Z)$ are topological spaces. Suppose that $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ is continuous. We must prove that $g\circ \pi:X\rightarrow Z$ is continuous; for it, we take an open set $A\subset Z$, ie $A\in \mathcal{T}_Z$ and we will show that $(g\circ \pi)^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{T}_X$.

Note first that $(g\circ \pi)^{-1}(A)=(\pi^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(A)=\pi^{-1}(g^{-1}(A))$.

Since $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ is continuous and $A\in \mathcal{T}_Z$, then $g^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{T}_Y$. Moreover, since $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map and also $g^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{T}_Y$, we have that $\pi^{-1}(g^{-1}(A))\in \mathcal{T}_X \Leftrightarrow (g\circ \pi)^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{T}_X$, As we wanted to try. Therefore, $g\circ \pi:X\rightarrow Z$ is continuous.

$\Leftarrow:$ Suppose that $g\circ \pi:X\rightarrow Z$ is continuous. We must prove that $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ is continuous; for it, we take an open set $B\subset Z$, ie $B\in \mathcal{T}_Z$ and we will show that $g^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{T}_Y$.

...

Someone could help me finish this proof, please.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that if $\pi : X \to Y$ is a quotient map then it is surjective, and $U \subset Y$ is open if and only if $\pi^{-1}(U) \subset X$ is.

With this in mind, let's take an open set $B$ of $Z$. Consider $g^{-1}(B)$. Because $g \circ \pi$ is continuous, $\pi^{-1}(g^{-1}(B))$ is open. So by the above, $g^{-1}(B)$ is open. Therefore $g$ is continuous.

Comment: When you say ''Consider $g^{-1}(B)$'', $g^{-1}(B)$ is considered a subset of $Y$, and so, $\pi^{-1}(g^{-1}(B))$ is open in $X$? Then $g^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{T}_Y$.

Comment: @Emmy Yes, $g^{-1}(B)$ is a subset of $Y$ that we want to show is open. We know that $\pi^{-1}(g^{-1}(B))$ is open in $X$, and because $\pi$ is a quotient map this means $g^{-1}(B)$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much.